# por que no reconoce mi diccionario pyton

Tags: python, diccionarios

```py
elige = {1:"enero", 2:"febrero", 3:"marzo",
4:"abril", 5:"mayo", 6:"junio", 7:"julio"}

argumento=int(input("ingrese numero de mes:",))


nombreDeMes=elige.get(argumento,"Mes invalido")
print(nombreDeMes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser un problema de formato: tienes dos instrucciones en la misma linea:

```
elige = {1:"enero", 2:"febrero", 3:"marzo", 4:"abril", 5:"mayo", 6:"junio", 7:"julio"}

argumento=int(input("ingrese numero de mes:"))

nombreDeMes=elige.get(argumento,"Mes invalido")
print(nombreDeMes)
```

produce:

```
ingrese numero de mes:1
enero

Process finished with exit code 0
```